# Need help (re)designing a database for a self-storage business

Tags: database, database-design

I apologize in advance for the overly-long post, but I wanted to provide as much information as possible.

I've been building web database apps for years, but I'm stuck on a redesign that I've been wanting to do forever and I cannot seem to figure out. I'm hoping for a nudge in the right direction.

The business is a self-storage rental business.  Tenants typically sign a contract/rental agreement with no specific end date and usually (but not always) pay each month on roughly the same day as their start date. So if you move in on the 16th, your rent is due on the 16th of every month (ignore those last few days of the month that not all months have).  Some folks pay 6 months in advance, etc.

Here are the tables that I know/think I need.

1. Tenants (basic contact info)
2. Storage Units (information about each unit, square footage, maybe base monthly rate unless I decide to stick those values in a separate table so that I can easily change the base rate for all units of the same type)
3. Tenants <-> Storage Units (One customer can rent multiple units, but each unit can only have 1 or 0 tenants so maybe this doesn't need it's own table.)

The part that I am stuck on is the best way to handle the billing - no invoices are generated - tenants just need to remember to pay.  I want to build this as a web app on a hosted provider so I don't know if I should be thinking about handling this with a nightly db script or from the web app side or if I can design it in a way that nothing special needs to happen each night.

Here's a simple example of what I need.

Joe rents Unit #1 on 1/1/2011 and pays for 1 month of rent ($50/month).

How do I build this so that if Joe doesn't pay for month 2 on 2/1/2011 he appears as past due and owing $50 (late fees also kick in after being late for 5 days and you are flagged for being locked out of your unit if you don't pay for 10 days). The employees have some discretion on late fees & lock outs if it's a long-time customer and they were just a little late, etc.

I think the most similar real-world design might be a cable television provider, but I'm having trouble putting it all together without making it overly complicated.

I will likely be building this in .NET 4 with MS SQL 2005/2008, but I don't think this is a technology-specific question.

Comment: Databases are for data, not for logic. You'll need to store your data in the database and perform your logic periodically via a program.

Comment: Thanks. I'd appreciate any suggestions regarding the schema design.

Answer (score 0):

If the three tables you listed are "obvious", it's equally clear that you'll need some tables for accounts payable and receivable.  If you don't already have something for the accounting side of the business you'll have to add it into your site.

I'd wonder about any business that didn't have some kind of accounting software in place.  The best thing, in my opinion, would be to find a way to let your web app tap into that data source in a secure, read-only way.

Comment: This is a very simple business that handles bills/payments on a cash basis. There is no real accounting software. Checks are created using Quicken. It would be cumbersome to sync up 3 sites with a bookkeeper located at a different location. The tenant database IS the accounts receivable data source. I would think it should be the opposite, that nightly the bookkeeper would connect to the tenant database to update receivables. I guess I should have simplified the essence of my question. What is a good schema for this assuming that there is no other data source? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like there is no good schema, because you're going to have duplication unless you link to a primary source.  You're hoping that it's easy, but it won't be.

Comment: So this is just a business that can't use a true relational database? I'm not looking for easy. I guess I feel much better now because it's obviously more complicated than I originally assumed. I suppose the answer would have been the same if I had just asked for schema suggestions for this business. I may just stick with the existing database. It's ugly, but it works. Thanks for the help.